# E[XY] = E[X]E[Y] for dependent RVs

Tags: probability, expectation

Let $Y_i$ be a sequence i.i.d random variables. I define 
$X = \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{k} Y_i} .$ Now, I'd like to calculate $E[Y_1X]$. Intuitively, this is just $1/k$ which seems to suggest $Y_1$ and $X$ are independent however, value of $X$ certainly depends on $Y_1$.

So, are X and $Y_i$ are independent or am I confusing things here? In general, what's the correct way to compute expectation here given that I know the distribution of $Y$ ?

Comment: The fact that expectation behaves as though variables were independent does not mean that variables are independent. For instance, for any two random variables $A, B$, we havbe $E(A + B) = E(A) + E(B)$. If you just take that formula at face value, it certainly feels like an independence property, but it is not. On the other hand, you can't _always_ expect expectation to behave as though all variables involved are independent.

Comment: Bu then what's the correct way to calculate the expectation?

Comment: @Arthur further I'm not sure if my intuitive expectation is correct.

Comment: @spiderrico your intuitive explanation is correct by symmetry, i.e. $E(Y_iX)$ are all equal and summing them up gives $1$.

Comment: Sorry but how is the (true) identity $$E(Y_1X)=\frac1k\tag{$\ast$}$$ supposed to suggest that $Y_1$ and $X$ are independent? Note that, except when the random variables $Y_i$ are constant, $$E(Y_1)E(X)\ne\frac1k$$ hence $(\ast)$ actually **disproves** that $Y_1$ and $X$ are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as Arthur says, the relation $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$ doesn't imply independence: Take any symmetric $X\in L^3$, then $\mathbb{E}[X\cdot X^2]=0=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[X^2]$.

Secondly, your intuition is correct: In order to compute $\mathbb{E}[Y_1 X]$ in your situation, the central observation is that the $Y_i X$, $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$, are identically distributed. Now you have $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i X=1$, so that
$$1=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^k Y_i X\right]=\sum_{i=1}^k\mathbb{E}\left[ Y_i X\right]=k\mathbb{E}[Y_1 X].$$

Comment: This cleared things. Thanks.